# Nuxtjs router go, routing _slug

Tags: routes, vue-router, nuxt.js

i'm a novice in nuxtjs. 
I have a following structure:

```
pages/
--| items/
-----| /info
---------| _slug.vue
```

I have a route 'website/items/info/39dj83'.

Where '39dj83' is a dynamic variable, that i got from API.

How can i redirect user to that route?

I'm trying something like this:

```
this.$router.push({name : 'items-info-slug', ???});
```

How can i send a slug '39dj83'??

Is my structure corrent?

Also how can i get this slug '39dj83' in my slug.vue component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.$router.push({name : 'items-info-slug',params: { slug: '39dj83' }});
```

[Docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)

In your _slug.vue you can access it via params. E.g.

```
fetch({params}) {
  console.log(params.slug)
}
```

[Docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you use a data that you got from your API; your structure should look like this:

pages/

--| items

-----| info

---------| _slug

--------------| index.vue

_slug is a folder, and index.vue contains the template, script and style that you had put in _slug.vue before.

To do redirection:

```
methods: {
goToSlugItem() {
    //not sure, it depends on your code
    this.$router.push("/items/info/_${item.slug}") 
  }
}
```

Sorry for my bad english, hope it helped.